# org.redisson.client.handler.PingConnectionHandler$1.run(PingConnectionHandler.java:79)

Tags: java, redis, redisson

I am using redisson `api 'org.redisson:redisson:3.13.6'` to consume redis(redis 6.2.5) stream in my java project. After running for months. shows error:

```
[02:45:28:123] [ERROR] - org.redisson.client.handler.PingConnectionHandler$1.run(PingConnectionHandler.java:79) - Unable to send PING command over channel: [id: 0x5aa1ca8d, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:56714]
org.redisson.client.RedisTimeoutException: Command execution timeout for command: (PING), params: [], Redis client: [addr=redis://cruise-redis-master.reddwarf-cache.svc.cluster.local:6379]
    at org.redisson.client.RedisConnection.lambda$async$1(RedisConnection.java:207) ~[redisson-3.13.6.jar!/:3.13.6]
    at org.redisson.client.RedisConnection$$Lambda$952/0x000000003818de40.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:715) [netty-common-4.1.70.Final.jar!/:4.1.70.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ImmediateExecutor.execute(ImmediateExecutor.java:34) [netty-common-4.1.70.Final.jar!/:4.1.70.Final]
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:703) [netty-common-4.1.70.Final.jar!/:4.1.70.Final]
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:790) [netty-common-4.1.70.Final.jar!/:4.1.70.Final]
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:503) [netty-common-4.1.70.Final.jar!/:4.1.70.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.70.Final.jar!/:4.1.70.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836) [?:?]
[02:45:28:126] [ERROR] - org.redisson.client.handler.PingConnectionHandler$1.run(PingConnectionHandler.java:79) - Unable to send PING command over channel: [id: 0x306c5661, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:56750]
org.redisson.client.RedisTimeoutException: Command execution timeout for command: (PING), params: [], Redis client: [addr=redis://cruise-redis-master.reddwarf-cache.svc.cluster.local:6379]
    at org.redisson.client.RedisConnection.lambda$async$1(RedisConnection.java:207) ~[redisson-3.13.6.jar!/:3.13.6]
    at org.redisson.client.RedisConnection$$Lambda$952/0x000000003818de40.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:715) [netty-common-4.1.70.Final.jar!/:4.1.70.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ImmediateExecutor.execute(ImmediateExecutor.java:34) [netty-common-4.1.70.Final.jar!/:4.1.70.Final]
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:703) [netty-common-4.1.70.Final.jar!/:4.1.70.Final]
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:790) [netty-common-4.1.70.Final.jar!/:4.1.70.Final]
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:503) [netty-common-4.1.70.Final.jar!/:4.1.70.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.70.Final.jar!/:4.1.70.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836) [?:?]
```

I could connection to redis success, some channels works fine, some channels failed. anyone facing the same problem?  why would this happen? what should I do to fix the problem?

Comment: In their FAQ, they have provided an answer for this exact issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70741301/org-redisson-client-handler-pingconnectionhandler1-runpingconnectionhandler-ja

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad, I have copied the wrong url, the correct one should be: https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/16.-FAQ#q-i-saw-a-redistimeoutexception-what-does-it-mean-what-shall-i-do-can-redisson-team-fix-it